# Facebook PHP example returning text instead of executing

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, output, sample

I'm trying to program a Facebook app using PHP. I've downloaded the PHP SDK from github (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) and I have the src files in the same directory on my server as my app.

I'm just trying to get a simple app up and running to play with, so I copied the code that accesses the user's profile from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi/.

Filling my app's information (censored the app id and secret), I get:

```
 <?php
  // Remember to copy files from the SDK's src/ directory to a
  // directory in your application on the server, such as php-sdk/
  require_once('facebook.php');

  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'CENSORED',
    'secret' => 'CENSORED',
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

  <?php
    if($user_id) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
        echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {

      // No user, print a link for the user to login
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    }

  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

However when I run this, it's like the code doesn't execute past the $config array. I just get a bunch of text in a massive paragraph as an output (I'm programming the app on Facebook with the canvas url and everything).

It looks something like this (censoreds are the app id and secret, respectively):

'CENSORED', 'secret' => 'CENSORED', ); $facebook = new Facebook($config); $user_id = $facebook->getUser(); ?> api('/me','GET'); echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name']; } catch(FacebookApiException $e) { // If the user is logged out, you can have a // user ID even though the access token is invalid. // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll // just ask the user to login again here. $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); echo 'Please login.'; error_log($e->getType()); error_log($e->getMessage()); } } else { // No user, print a link for the user to login $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); echo 'Please login.'; } ?>

I've spent a few days on this and the lack of n00b-level documentation from Facebook isn't helping. So why am I getting a bunch of text instead of the intended output?

Some guesses to get you started:
 1. Something is deprecated in the code somewhere and no longer works
 2. I need more files that just the ones in src 
 3. PHP isn't being handled properly by my server or Facebook (seems
    unlikely)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're getting the raw PHP code. If you do a 'view source' in the browser, you'll see the PHP tags, which the browser is trying to render as html. Your server is misconfigured and/or doesn't have PHP installed.

Comment: Hmm... it seems the file needed to be saved as ".php" istead of ".html" so the server could figure out what to do with it. Thanks!